# Going to web link from Alert Box

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how I could go to a website by clicking on the "OK" button in a alert box.
Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<script>alert(123)
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    alert(123);

    // go to whereever you want
    window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
</script>
```

`alert` is blocking, so it waits until you click OK to continue executing code.

Answer (score 0):

The code after your `alert()` function will be executed when the user presses 'Okay',  so put the following code after your `alert()` function:

```
window.location.href = '...';
```

This will change the the user's window's location go to `...`
Replace `...` with the URI.

You could also call the `window.location.replace()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You better use a confirm than an alert:

```
if (confirm('go to stackoverflow?'))
{
    window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
}
else
{
    // Clicked no
}
```